# Are these screws / anchors good enough for mounting this decorative shelf on drywall?

Tags: screws, mounting, shelving, drywall-anchor, shelf

See the images below. Are these small screws suitable for mounting this on drywall? If not, what should I be using?

[image: screws and hole]
[image: shelf full view with screws]

I have two of these decorative shelves that are intended to display a few kids’ books on a drywall wall. I expect the load will be relatively low because the books aren’t heavy and the shelf isn’t thick enough to hold books with their spine facing out, so you can’t fit that many on it anyway. The shelf itself isn’t very heavy (913 g according to my scale). The shelves are 55 cm long, 12 cm high, 8 cm deep, and the holes are 42 cm apart (6 cm from base).

The portion of the wall is relative short so there don’t seem to be studs in the right spots for mounting.

Comment: Depends how much weight the shelf is intended to carry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a light shelf like that where nobody dies if it gets yanked off the wall, your anchors will work.

Those anchors are pretty easy to patch up if you ever get rid of the shelf. That's one criterion for choosing such anchors. @RDman's nylon ribbed anchors fit this pattern and are probably stronger, easier to remove, and easier to patch.

Alternatively you can select anchors designed for unscrewing and rescrewing. When you go to paint that room, for instance, such anchors prove useful. If I have to hang a curtain from drywall, I'll always use such anchors. @RDman's pop toggles look well tuned to this purpose. I keep [these anchors](https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=12239) laying around for this purpose:

[image: Installed anchor]
[image: Unused anchor]

Answer (score 3):

The anchors that you show **can** be used to mount the shelf.

However I prefer [nylon ribbed anchors](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/hardware/screws-and-anchors/anchors/5036439?store=18608&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhfipBhCqARIsAH9msblXN5eR0eV6158qyN38x4M5toXSVaHH2hM87NnTd-KwqYQzeQTzVfkaAnfSEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) as they have a better holding capacity. They come in various sizes to hold various weights.

[Pop Toggles](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/hardware/screws-and-anchors/anchors/5334602?store=18608&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhfipBhCqARIsAH9msbkOnHlJpihD36ro9cy20ABbMjrjNLUfSd3VKYAEmTXaNfdjzvAuDosaAnNaEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) are even better.